# Property 'onSubmit' does not exist on type 'CampaignComponent'

Tags: angular, api

So I'm trying to make my app to send some data to API. Currently the problem is that when I use the ng serve, I got-> error TS2339:Property 'onSubmit' does not exist on type 'CampaignComponent'.

It is only okay when I remove the onSubmit in the form.

campaign.component.html

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card card-primary">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">Add Campaign</h3>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-header -->
      <!-- form start -->
      <form #userPost="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userPost.value)">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nama Campaign</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              name="name"
              id="exampleInputEmail1"
              ngModel
              placeholder="Nama Campaign"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-body -->

        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
  </div>
</div>
```

campaign.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetServiceService } from '../get-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-campaign',
  templateUrl: './campaign.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./campaign.component.css'],
})
export class CampaignComponent implements OnInit {
  campaigns;
  constructor(private campaignService: GetServiceService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.campaigns = this.campaignService.getCampaign();
  }
}
```

[image: This is the error in cmd]

this is the same code from my question (after change) in [Angular12 get API making table data not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69370690/angular12-get-api-making-table-data-not-showing)

Comment: The error is clear, you don't have `onSubmit` method in `CampaignComponent`. You need to write that method.

Comment: Add method `onSubmit(value){

}` in your `CampaignComponent`

Comment: thx a lot for the help

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

As you have defined **onSubmit()** function on your **campaign.component.html** file

```
<form #userPost="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userPost.value)">
```

so you required to define that same function in **campaign.component.ts** file too..

```
 onSubmit(formValue){
      console.log(formValue)
    }
```